# What frequency bandwidth should an accelerometer operate for measuring punching and kicking movements?

Tags: filter, frequency, bandwidth, bypass-capacitor, high-pass-filter

I'm trying to choose the bypass capacitors for a schematic circuit that measures the acceleration (in g) for punching, kicking, throwing, etc. But I don't know what to place on the x, y, z output of the accelerometer ([ADXL-377](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADXL377.pdf) - page 9) because I don't know what bandwidth I should choose.

What could be consider a proper bandwidth for measuring these types of movements?

Comment: Sounds like an opportunity for experimentation.

Comment: You use the physics of motion to initially estimate a coarse number for your acceleration targets and then you get smart about your processing steps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This article](http://www.connectsavannah.com/savannah/the-true-force-of-a-boxers-punch/Content?oid=2133328) talks about 50g and milliseconds for boxing. Based on that, you should maybe start out with the full BW (1kHz'ish). By experiments, you may learn that this can be dialed back later.

BTW: I once connected an ADXL-xxx device to a [Logomatic datalogger](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12772) (both the accelerometer and a flat LiIon battery fitted nicely on the back of the PCB). That proved very useful for similar experiments. Maybe you can do the same thing. I suspect you don't want to use a smartphone for initial experiments...